Incrementing row reference after 3 iterations
I'm having trouble trying to solve how to run this function =IF($Page1.C3<>"",G2+1,"") the function is working but for a easy replicate I need for the C row to increment by one once every 3 iterations of the function while the other references increment normally as the function is dragged down the column.

=IF($Datos.C2<>"";1;"") [This is the formula for the first 3 rows]
=IF($Datos.C3<>"";G2+1;"") [This is the formula that has to increment over the relation previously mentioned]
I looked at the documentation but found only to use the function ROW() with some other formula, but  either I fail to implement it over the function or it is not intended to fix this.

Yes, ROW() is the solution. I wasn't sure whether you meant that G2+1 goes by threes, or just C3, so here is a formula that does both.
=IF(INDIRECT("Datos.C"&CEILING(ROW()/3))<>"";INDIRECT("G"&CEILING(ROW()/3))+1;"")

Result when Datos.C3 is empty (but not the rest of Datos column C) and column G has numbers 1,2 and so on:
1
1
1
2
2
2



4
4
4

